# Infimum of a measure

Tags: limits, measure-theory, continuity, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose you have a sequence of measurable sets $A_n$ and a measure $\mu$. Then I believe,  $\mu(\bigcap_n A_n)=\mu(\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n)\le \inf_{n\in\mathbb N}\mu(A_n)$ holds true.

> How does one verify that inequality properly?

Comment: Where does $\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n$ stand for?

Comment: is this not the same like $\bigcap_n A_n$

Comment: If the collection of sets is equipped with inclusion as partial order then: "yes". So there is nothing wrong with it. Only it is a bit redundant, because the intersection will do without mentioning any order.

Comment: If is best not to write $\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n$.  Just write $\bigcap_n A_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} A_n$ then $A\subseteq A_n$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$, whence $\mu A\leq \mu A_n$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$.

That means that $\mu A$ is a lower bound of the set $\{\mu A_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ so that: $$\mu A\leq\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}\mu(A_n)$$